# Garage fiberglass ceiling is wet

Tags: insulation, garage, fiberglass

After living approximately 1 year in my new home, this October I started to insulate my garage by putting fiber glass - with the intention of putting drywall after.

Couple of weeks ago I have noticed that some parts of the insulation under the ceiling gets wet.

I am in Colorado where it snows every now and then so the first thing I though was that I had a leak somewhere, even though I never noticed any water/wetness while installing the insulation or during the time living there without any insulation.

Regardless, I have removed some panels to check out and I did not find any water or dampness in general.

I have also noticed that they are always the **same** spots that get wet. I have attached some photos here to show what I am talking about.

Does anybody have any clue of what could it be? How can I remediate/fix the problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Dry as Colorado air might be, I'd bet that's *condensation* from humid indoor air, where the where a gap in the insulation by a stud gets cold from the outside air. Try tacking a vapor barrier over the inside, to separate humidified air from the cold.

Comment: Would install drywall fix the solution without having to put a vapor barrier?- Or to ask a better question, if I put a vapor barrier and then the dry wall - wouldn't the condensation "stop" at the drywall?

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect condensation on your cold roof dripping down to that spot. I would check the walls to see if any moisture (possibly mold) is also behind the insulation. **You really need to put up proper vapor barrier ASAP to prevent moisture migrating to cold areas.**

To resolve this before it gets worse:

1. Take down current insulation
2. treat any mold and dry out walls / ceiling
3. throw out any wet insulation
4. replace insulation after walls / ceiling are dry
5. apply vapor barrier over insulation and tape seams
6. adding drywall is optional

Comment: I do not have attic space over that area. It's a flat roof without shingles. Actually it has a very small slope towards the alley area.

Comment: @Vincenzo - either way you need to put up some vapor barrier

Comment: Oh that for sure, I will remove the fiberglass and make sure it's dry.

I was just clarifying that there is no attic - since you were assuming it in the response you gave, and was wondering if such info would change anything in your response

Comment: @Vincenzo - same thing - when moisture is hitting the cold roof either a flat roof or higher up it will condense and create problems. Added remediation steps to my answer

Comment: Thank you very much - will do!

Answer (score 0):

Pull the insulation down now and check above it. I bet you'll find a ton of mold up there.

How do I know this? I made the same mistake. I insulated my shed roof garage, figuring no big deal as it was unheated, I'd get the vapor barrier in sooner or later, etc, etc. Then I started seeing spots of water on the insulation. I pulled it down and there was massive amounts of mold and fungus above it. Apparently the temperature shift of the roof sheathing plus moisture I brought in to the garage resulted in all the humidity getting up there over the insulation.

The ultimate fix in my situation was to scrub off and bleach the wood, then to have the ceiling reinsulated with spray foam. This encapsulated the remaining mold and provided a vapor barrier along with the insulation. Alternate approaches would have been to add venting above the insulation, then a vapor barrier below, or to just make a full sealed off roof assembly. With a shed roof that's a bit of a headache, and as a result there's a few different approaches to the details that you should investigate before making any choices. Search 'venting insulated shed roof' or similar on your favorite search engine to start down that particular rabbit hole.

So, as I said at the top, pull down some insulation and check. If you're lucky and there's no mold, just moisture, get the space dehumdified until it's solidly dry, fix your roof venting, then put the insulation back up with a full vapor barrier immediately. Or do what I did and switch to spray foam.